# Folium of Descartes parametrization covering the entire curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We have the parametrization of the Folium of Descartes $$x=\frac{3t}{1+t^3}$$ and $$y=\frac{3t^2}{1+t^3}$$. I am trying to show that over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, the this parametrization covers the entire curve. I am getting a Groebner Basis of the form $x^3 - 3xy + y^3, x^2 - 3y + ty^2, tx - y, -3t + x + t^2y$, but I cannot extend any solution $(x,y) \in V(<x^3-3x^2y+y^3>)$ since the coefficients of $t$ in the other elements of the Groebner Basis would also vanish, anyone has any suggestions on how to proceed with the problem?

THanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From your grobner-base (or from the original equations) one can read off, that $t=y/x$ for all $(x,y)$ in $C$ (the cartesian leaf) where $x \neq 0$. But if $x=0$, then on $C = V(x^3- 3 x y + y^3)$ we have $y=0$ too. Now the point $(0,0)$ is just the image of $t=0$ in the original parametrization.